# How to use Regex to replace a tag in a word document with Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

First post on stackoverflow for me so sorry if something is out of norm or similar ^^

Currently I'm trying to find a way to read vouchers out of a .csv that I get from my pfsense.
Plan is to read it out of the .csv and write it down in a Word document so that secretaries can print it out and give them out to coworkers.

So far I have no problems replacing names and room numbers, all I gotta do now is to find a way to replace the voucher codes, but since they obviously always change I tried to use regex, here's the current state of that part of my code:

```
if ($Vouchers -match '((\d|\w){11})*') { 
$matches.0 }

ReplaceTag –Document $Doc -FindText ‘<Vouchers>’ -replacewithtext $matches
```

The regex itself is working perfectly fine (already tested it on regex101) so I guess it's the code.
I'm assuming that it's trying to literally match "((\d|\w){11})*" instead of using the pattern :\

Any kinda help would be welcomed!

Comment: Note that `(\d|\w)` = `\w`.